# Sorry, you don't have permission to download this app.message occure when downloading app in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, app-store

I uploaded beta version of my application in windows phone 8 app store.Now i got one link from app store when i click this link from my nokia lumia 520 in india than its downloaded successfully.

But when i send this link to my friend at africa and they click on link and it gives message like "Sorry, you don't have permission to download this app.message occure"

Comment: This problem is from microsoft or any thing else?

Comment: Beta are closed and work only with invitations. Have you added the live id of your friend to the list of allowed users on the devcenter?

Comment: @KooKiz:thanks for replying but i dont know how to added the live id of my friend to the list of allowed users on the devcenter

Comment: @KooKiz:I just upload beta version of  my application in my developer account.now it generate one link and this link i past on my windows phone browser.and application downloaded.no done any signin process in my phone also

Comment: @KooKiz:If possible than give me some stap to add my friend allow user

Comment: May be this [links] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598) helps you know more about the beta release.                Just delete the current app and upload a new app with others live id. so that they can also use it.

Comment: Also, this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7204a3c1-2913-4278-8788-047334349a48/how-to-add-new-email-accounts-for-existing-beta-app  Apparently you can add new users by going through the update submitting process

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access for each beta users individually. You'll need to whitelist their Microsoft account (formerly Windows Live ID).

You can do it at the submission page:

[image]

Comment: Whitelist means you need to grant access to users explicitly. Added screenshot for more clarification.

Comment: Hello Andras , how to redirected(link) to above page as u show in screen shot pls guide.thanks